# How to configure dynamic loading?

Tags: javascript, webpack, dynamic-import

I'm using webpack `4.26.1` (latest).

The code `import('./images/header.csv')` produce the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module './images/header.csv'
>       at webpackMissingModule (home.js:9)

My project structure:

```
'project-dir/src/components/home.js' (im here)
'project-dir/src/components/images/header.csv'
```

---

I tried to read https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/ but failed to understand what to do except adding random webpack comments which I don't understand.

Also, from the docs, I may be found the source of the problem but I'm not exactly sure I understand it and how to solve it.

> Fully dynamic statements, such as import(foo), will fail because webpack requires at least some file location information. This is because foo could potentially be any path to any file in your system or project. The import() must contain at least some information about where the module is located, so bundling can be limited to a specific directory or set of files.
>
> Every module that could potentially be requested on an import() call is included. For example, import(`./locale/${language}.json`) will cause every .json file in the ./locale directory to be bundled into the new chunk. At run time, when the variable language has been computed, any file like english.json or german.json will be available for consumption. Using the webpackInclude and webpackExclude options allows us to add regex patterns that reduce the files that webpack will bundle for this import.

---

**More than providing me a solution, I will *appreciate* any answer that covers *what* is the actual problem with my code.**

Thank you.

Comment: Dynamic imports, that is the function `import()` only work on modules at this time,to use your CSV data you have to use the regular ES6 `import` or CommonJS `require()`

Comment: thanks for the imformation. From your words, I maybe didn't undersand the following article: https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/webpack-and-dynamic-imports-doing-it-right-72549ff49234 which talkes on how to dynamiclly import images. Am I missing something? (the relevant title: Problems while loading files).

Comment: I was not aware that Webpack did this for dynamic imports, thanks for the article, but after looking at the article, you have to be using `file-loader` https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader and then configure it not only to pick up images but also CSV files in your case.

Comment: thanks but I still get the same error.

Comment: Hey Stav, I had a similar issue recently, can you try giving the path from the root of your project like this - import('../../../project-dir/src/components/images/header.csv') After I gave the path from entry point, it was able to find the module.

Comment: @clever_bassi it's not working. can you share a working project?

Comment: yes messaged you on gitter.